# Можно ли превратить unlogged table в НЕ unlogged table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.5

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли превратить unlogged table в НЕ unlogged table, то есть в обычную постоянную таблицу?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, стало возможно [как раз в 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE table_test SET LOGGED
```

---

Источник: [[SO] How to apply PostgreSQL UNLOGGED feature to an existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7938610/2076787)

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename SET LOGGED
```

[Добавили](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html) эти возможность только в 9.5, но судя по тегам, вас это ограничение устроит.